# How to Allow clients to skip consent in openam13

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openam, openid-connect, forgerock

I am using Forgerock OpenAM 13.0.0 as an identity provider.

I have configured OIDC under a particular realm in it.

Whenever I try to log in using my application each time it asks to allow or deny option.

How to skip consent option after the first login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in **13.5.0**.

[OAuth2 user consent confirmation can be optional](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-5093)

If you want to skip the page, you should change the source code of OpenAM.

Comment: I am using version 13.0.0. I dont want to update to other version. Is it possible in the current 13.0.0 version?

Comment: I think you can solve the problem by applying [this commit](https://github.com/WrenSecurity/wrenam/commit/d4422243ae9283c0c741e0a988fb48ae91be3b93).